# If and else won't work

Tags: php, if-statement

So, I guess this is pretty simple, but I can't really figure it out.

I'm trying to display a discount price, if it's set in the databse, and if not, display the regular price.

It displays the discount price if it's there, but it doesn't display the regular price, if it's not there?

```
if (isset($row['discount']))
      {
        echo $row['discount'];
      }

      else
      {
        echo $row['price'];
      }
```

**Var dump**

```
300 array(14) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(14) "Shoon slips UK" ["navn"]=> string(14) "Shoon slips UK" [2]=> string(17) "Importeret fra UK" ["tekst"]=> string(17) "Importeret fra UK" [3]=> string(3) "450" ["pris"]=> string(3) "450" [4]=> string(3) "300" ["tilbud"]=> string(3) "300" [5]=> string(59) "http://localhost/slipseknuden/assets/img/slips/slips1_2.jpg" ["billede"]=> string(59) "http://localhost/slipseknuden/assets/img/slips/slips1_2.jpg" [6]=> string(5) "Shoon" ["ka
```

**The whole code**

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM produkt ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left media-middle">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object sideobject" src="<? echo $row['billede']; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['navn']; ?>">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">

    <h3><? echo $row['navn']; ?></h3>
    <p><? echo $row['tekst']; ?>...</p>

    <?php

      if (isset($row['tilbud']))
      {
        echo $row['tilbud'];
      }
      else
      {
        echo $row['pris'];
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your query failed. An `if/else` without anything else isn't enough code.

Comment: Then what do I need to do?

Comment: You post more code and DB schema. Plus, you may not have selected that row in your query.

Comment: Removing space didn't help.

Comment: Add the code where you store something in $row['discount'] variable

Comment: Can you show us  `var_dump($row)` ?

Comment: Actually your $row is an empty array that's why its not working. try to print this and then you will get what is actual problem

Comment: Just updated the question with var_dump

Comment: discount = tilbud
price = pris

Comment: So try to replace discount by tilbud and price by pris in you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try this.

```
<?php

  if (isset($row['tilbud']) && !empty($row['tilbud']))
  {
    echo $row['tilbud'];
  }
  else
  {
    echo $row['pris'];
  }

?>
```

I guess even though discount value is not there the variable will be still there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) please try using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead. While some systems seem to allow `isset` for checking a key in an array, I learned the hard way a while back that some do not.

```
if( array_key_exists('discount',$row) )
    echo $row['discount'];
else
    echo $row['price'];
```